# Exception when using more than two mocks in a test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit, autofixture

I am writing a test using `xUnit 2` and `AutoFixture` for a .Net Core 2.2 project. I require three Mocks in the test to satisfy the system under test and previously AutoFixture had no problem doing this. However now when I add more than two mocks to the test signature I get an exception.

```
[Theory]
[AutoData]
public void ContrivedTest(
   Mock<IDependencyOne> mockDependencyOne,
   Mock<IDependencyTwo> mockDependencyTwo)
{
    Assert.True(true);
}
```

Will work as expected, but:

```
[Theory]
[AutoData]
public void ContrivedTest(
   Mock<IDependencyOne> mockDependencyOne,
   Mock<IDependencyTwo> mockDependencyTwo,
   Mock<IDependencyThree> mockDependencyThree)
{
    Assert.True(true);
}
```

Throws the following exception:

> ---- System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> -------- System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: value

This question (almost word for word) was recently asked on the [AutoFixture Github](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/1116), but the supplied answer:

> AutoData and InlineAutoData do not become aware of Moq when you just install the AutoFixture.AutoMoq package. Instead, you should create your own data attributes derived from the default ones, customize fixture with Moq support and use them

Doesn't make sense to me. Why should two mocks work but not three? How does creating my own data attribute help, and exactly how should I customise fixture with Moq support?

It's worth noting that I'm not using `AutoMoq` as I've never needed to in the past. I could just as easily new up the mocks myself in the test and I intend to as I need it working, but I'm curious as to why something that used to work just fine no longer does: Was I using it wrong all along and it just worked by happy chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autofixture uses round-robin to assign default values therefore it fails on 3 mocks. This is an explanation on Autofixture issues page.

> The issue happens when AutoFixture tries to auto-assign properties to
>   a newly created Mock object. The auto-generated DefaultValue property
>   doesn't suits very well, so Moq fails. For the enum values AutoFixture
>   uses the round-robin strategy, which explains why the case with 2
>   mocks works, while 3 mocks start to crash it.

You can read the [full comment here](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/1082#issuecomment-444630742)

Comment: That's a much clearer explanation and I'm not sure how I didn't find it before - not seeing the wood for the trees in my search results probably - although it's still not obvious *why* it used to work and now doesn't. I assume they changed their strategy and that's caused the issue. I think I'll stick to newing up the mocks since although the custom attribute posited by Mark Seeman works, I don't really want to have to have either a custom attribute in every test project or have to think of somewhere common to place it where it can be used, not forgotten about and maintained by someone. Thanks

Comment: The preferable way indeed depends on a level of AutoFixture integration in your project. In most projects I work on we integrate AutoFixture deeply from the very first day, so the default `AutoData` is never used. Instead, we agreed to always use our own attribute to have no confusion. This not only provides with a flexibility to globally customize AutoFixture, but also ensures that all tests are consistent and look similarly. Anyway, if you eventually prefer to stick to the `AutoData`, be also aware of the `NoAutoProperties` attribute, which might help to solve the issue as well.